# Scrollviewer to Display a Bigger Image on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I need to display a bigger image at original scale on a Windows Phone 8.1 App.

tried
ScrollViewer
and ViewBox.

None of them seems to work fine.

I want something like when an image is displayed in an html page, scrollable , movable, etc.

Any Idea whether it can be done without embedding a webbrowser ?

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Image Source="Assets/MyImage.png" Stretch="None" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViewer is designed to handle content that is bigger than the surrounding container.You can scroll image by put image in grid try like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="Assets/MyImage.png" Stretch="None" />
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In case if Grid is much smaller than the Scroll-viewer then try by giving height and width attribute to scroll viewer